# New to C, trouble with error messages for a blackjack-like program

Tags: c

So I am writing a program in class that is similar to blackjack and I am getting the following errors:

```
ThirtyNine.c:27:54: error: expected expression before 'int'
                 (playerdie1,playerdie2,playerdie3) = int initial3roll();
                                                      ^
ThirtyNine.c:28:60: error: expected expression before 'int'
                 (opponentdie1,opponentdie2,opponentdie3) = int initial3roll();
                                                            ^
ThirtyNine.c:29:60: error: expected ')' before string constant
                     printf("You roll 3 dice: ", playerdie1 " ", playerdie2, " ", playerdie3);
                                                            ^
ThirtyNine.c:29:60: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
ThirtyNine.c:30:69: error: expected ')' before string constant
                     printf("Opponent rolls 3 dice: ", (opponentdie1 " ", opponentdie2, " ", opponentdie3);
                                                                     ^
ThirtyNine.c:30:106: error: expected ')' before ';' token
                     printf("Opponent rolls 3 dice: ", (opponentdie1 " ", opponentdie2, " ", opponentdie3);
                                                                                                          ^
ThirtyNine.c:92:37: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
                                     }
                                     ^
ThirtyNine.c:92:37: error: expected ';' before '}' token
```

This is my code so far, any help will be appreciated!

```
int initial3roll();
int main(){
    int playerdie1,playerdie2,playerdie3;
    int opponentdie1,opponentdie2,opponentdie3;
    int playertotal;
    int opponenttotal;
    int select1;
    int diceroll;
        printf("Welcome to the game of 39!\n Press 1 to start or 0 to exit:");
        scanf( "%d", &select1 );

    if ( select1 == 0) {
        exit(0);
}
else {
    int initial3roll();{
    int die1 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
    int die2 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
    int die3 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
    return (die1,die2,die3);
      }
        while (select1 == 1){
            (playerdie1,playerdie2,playerdie3) = int initial3roll();
            (opponentdie1,opponentdie2,opponentdie3) = int initial3roll();
                printf("You roll 3 dice: ", playerdie1 " ", playerdie2, " ", playerdie3);
                printf("Opponent rolls 3 dice: ", (opponentdie1 " ", opponentdie2, " ", opponentdie3);
                    playertotal = playerdie1 + playerdie2 + playerdie3;
                    opponenttotal = opponentdie1 + opponentdie2 + opponentdie3;
                        printf("Your total: ", playertotal);
                        printf("Opponent total: ", opponenttotal);
                        printf("How many dice do you want to roll again: ");
                        scanf("&d", &diceroll );
                    switch(diceroll){
                        case '1' int die1 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
                            printf("You roll 1 die: ", die1);
                            playertotal += die1;
                            die1 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
                            printf("Opponent rolls 1 die: ", die1);
                            opponenttotal += die1;
                            printf("Your total is: ", playertotal);
                            printf("Opponent total is: ", opponenttotal);
                                break;
                        case '2'
                        int die1 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
                        int die2 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
                            printf("You roll 2 die: ", die1, die2);
                            playertotal += die1 + die2;
                            die1 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
                            die2 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
                            printf("Opponent rolls 2 die: " die1, die2);
                            opponenttotal += die1 + die2;
                            printf("Your total is: ", playertotal);
                            printf("Opponent total is: ", opponenttotal);
                                break;
                        case '3'
                        int die1 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
                        int die2 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
                        int die3 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
                            printf("You roll 3 die: ", die1, die2,die3);
                            playertotal += die1 + die2 + die3;
                            die1 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
                            die2 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
                            die3 = 1 + (rand() % 12);
                            printf("Opponent rolls 3 die: " die1, die2, die3);
                            opponenttotal += die1 + die2 + die3;
                            printf("Your total is: ", playertotal);
                            printf("Opponent total is: ", opponenttotal);
                                break;
                        default:
                            printf("Your total is: ", playertotal);
                            printf("Opponent total is: ", opponenttotal);
                                break;
                    }
                        if (playertotal > opponenttotal);
                            printf("You Win!");
                        if (opponenttotal > playertotal);
                            printf("You Lose");
                        if (opponenttotal = playertotal);
                            printf("You Tie");


                        printf("Press 1 to play again or 0 to exit:");
                        scanf( "%d", &select1 );
                        if (select1 == 0){
                            printf("Thanks for playing!");
                                exit(0);
                        }
                                }

}
                        return(0);
```

}

Comment: There are too many mistakes in this program to list them all - my advice is to go and learn C.

Comment: @immibis Any idea on where to start for this program?

Comment: The game must follow this format exactly, so if it seems a little odd at points, I was trying to match this.

Comment: Welcome to the game of 39!
Press 1 to start or 0 to exit: 1
You roll 3 dice: 4 10 3
Opponent rolls 3 dice: 6 5 11
Your total: 17
Opponent total: 22
How many dice do you want to roll again: 2
You roll 2 dice: 12 10
Opponent rolls 2 dice: 3 10
Your total: 39
Opponent total: 35
You win!
Press 1 to play again or 0 to exit: 0
Thanks for playing!
There are 3 outcomes to the game with the following messages:
Win: you get closer to 39 than your opponent or opponent busts
You Win!
Lose: your opponent gets closer to 39 or you bust
You Lose!
Tie: both have the same total or both bust
You Tie!

Comment: You have so many problems here. Read a book or attend a class, then start the code over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things that stand out:

1) Read about how to use [`printf`](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html) -- it's pretty different if you're new to C. You pass it a single string as the first parameter and a list of args as the rest, and you represent the args in the string using % followed by a type identifier. For example: `%d` for an int, so:

```
printf("You roll 3 dice: %d %d %d", playerdie1, playerdie2, playerdie3);
```

2) C does not have nested functions; you'll want to move your definition of `int initial3roll()` outside of `main` on it's own. It should look similar to your definition of `main`.

3) C does not have tuples, so this won't work:

```
(playerdie1,playerdie2,playerdie3) = int initial3roll();
```

You'll have to return a single `int` from `initial3roll` unless you want to use pointers or pass in reference parameters. You might want to consider just running this function 3 times instead, one roll each, to simplify things. Or just remove it altogether and use `rand` on its own.

4) Each `case` needs a colon after the number and should probably be on its own line (for clarity). The `default` case is correct.

5) Make things easier on yourself and properly indent your code. Your editor can probably do this for you; search around for how. It's hard to follow like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a buddy of mine helped me with this and he hadn't used C in a while, so it makes sense that the syntax is off. Also my professor is very bad at explaining things as he basically reads off of a powerpoint.

Comment: @stabby Sure thing. By the way, I see that you're a new user. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.